# Unable to browse Integration Services on SQL 2016

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2016

I've installed SQL Server 2016 (Standard Edition) on a Windows Server 2016, selecting Integration Services to be installed too. I've also installed SSMS and SSDT from the same installation media.

I am running SSMS as administrator and can connect to the local Database engine.

My user is a Windows and SQL Server admin.

However I cannot connect (explicitly using the server name) or even browse to the local Integration Services?

Receiving the following error.

[SSIS not browsable and can't connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbrHS.jpg)

Having already searched for an answer to this problem, many suggest checking that the service is running etc. which can be seen in the Services and SQL Configuration Manager.

[Services shown as running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcppz.jpg)

I've also tried turning off the Windows Firewall to establish if that is the cause of the problem but it had no effect.

Anyone got any ideas what might be preventing it from being accessible?

Comment: Did you check over at [dba.se]? You may find existing answers rather there than here.

Comment: @Filburt No joy.

Comment: Did you update SSMS to the latest version? SSMS v17 seems to have a bug where it can't connect to Integration Services.

Comment: Spot on Rich! Uninstalling v17 and installing v16.5.3. instead resolved the issue. Many thanks. Download link here...https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/previous-sql-server-management-studio-releases

Comment: Rich's comment should be posted as the answer so others will be able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem last month. In my case I had to install the 32-bit version of access database engine (on my 64 bit windows).

Sql data tools works with 32-bit

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Answer (score 0):

The later SSMS versions (16.x and 17.x) will only connect to their respective versions SQL 2016 and SQL 2017. Microsoft is planning to retire the older method in favor of the SSISDB, which is more secure.

[Link to the official statement from Microsoft (in the note box).](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/service/integration-services-service-ssis-service#manage-the-service)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and the solution was to install the old interface on top of the existing one (SQL Server Management Studio 2016). [Here's link to the installation file](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=840946). After having installed this, I can now connect to the integration services. You will have to set it up of course and give yourself [Rights](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107501/how-to-install-ssis-on-sql-server-2014)